# How to use HttpURLConnection in Android to post data?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I want to send json data via stream to the server, but I struggle to make it work.
I have the following method:

```
String data = "{\"id\":\"2633\",\"f_name\":\"Test\",\"l_name\":\"Aplikace\",\"city\":\"Nymburk\",\"address\":\"Testovaci 123456789 xyz\",\"psc\":\"288 02\"}";


private String httpPost(String urlString, String data, String session_per) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String s1 = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        String s2 = "";
        HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpurlconnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpurlconnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",session_per);
        httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Authentication-Token", GlobalVar.KLIC);
        httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpurlconnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        OutputStreamWriter outStrWrt = new OutputStreamWriter(httpurlconnection.getOutputStream());
        outStrWrt.write(data);
        outStrWrt.close();

        String s3 = httpurlconnection.getResponseMessage();
        //dataoutputstream.flush();
        //dataoutputstream.close();
        InputStream inputstream = httpurlconnection.getInputStream();
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
        int i;
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        s1 = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        s1 = "";
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this won't work? The cookies etc. are all correct. Did I miss something important? This is like the 6th method I am trying and I'm starting to get desperate :D
Thank you!

EDIT:

It succesfully connects and the server responds, but it doesn't update user data, as if the json didn't get to the server correctly.

If my Java code is correct there may be a server-side issue.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Errors? Exceptions? Which return value do you get?

Comment: `outStrWrt.close();` Remove that statement.

Comment: `s1 = "";` Not very informative for the caller. Change to something like `s1 = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();`.

Comment: @blackapps The close doesn't actually do anything here, and it doesn't bear on the OP's problem, whatever it may be.

Comment: `sb.append(line);` That should be `sb.append(line).append("\n");`.

Comment: `The cookies etc. are all correct. `  What do you mean? Do they arrive correct at the server?

Comment: Yes the cookies do arrive - I tried removing outStrWrt.close(); and now I get this exception from the server: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to decode JSON object' in /data/web/virtuals/32157/virtual/www/api/UpdateUserApi.php:25Stack trace:#0

Comment: So it looks you sent wrong json. And you did not show what you send.

Comment: The json is in String format like this: "{\"id\":\"2633\",\"f_name\":\"Test\",\"l_name\":\"Aplikace\",\"city\":\"Nymburk\",\"address\":\"Testovaci 123456789 xyz\",\"psc\":\"288 02\"}";

Comment: If your php script causes exceptions then you should post the script code.

Comment: The exception happens only if I remove OutStrWrt.close(), otherwise there is no exception.

Comment: Please put the json in your post. Assign it to a variable there so we can follow the flow of your code.

Comment: But you see the exception in Android? Or where?

Comment: I print server response to console. Normally it should be "result: true" and IT IS, however it doesn't update user data - that's why I asked the question, to see if my method is incorrect in some way.

Comment: You did not tell where you see that exception. You do nothing with an exception message in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flush()` method,you don't close this output stream before you read all bytes

```java
outStrWrt.flush();
InputStream inputstream=httpurlconnection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 11, you can try to use `HttpClient` too.
E.g:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(urlString)).header("Cookie",session_per).header("Authentication-Token",GlobalVar.KLIC).header("Content-type","application/json").POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data)).build();
String datas=client.send(request,BodyHandlers.ofString());
return datas;
```